# Valgrind OpenMPI

Tags: c++, valgrind, openmpi, address-sanitizer

I am trying to check some code that uses openMPI, since it seems to leak memory.

I am using valgrind, and although I am using the suppressionflag for openMPI, i get a whole bunch of leaks and errors for the trivial code below. I know that openMPI is not "valgrind clean" but as far I understand, this should be handled by the suppression file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    MPI_Init(0, NULL);
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Do I use the suppression file in a wrong way? Or is there simply no better way? I have also tried Sanitizer, which gives me more or less the same....

PS: I am calling Valgrind with 

`mpirun -np 2 valgrind --suppressions=/usr/share/openmpi/openmpi-valgrind.supp --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --log-file=valgrind%p-out.txt .testProg`

Comment: You are using the right syntax and this is what openmpi developers recommend doing https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#valgrind_clean. As a personal note I must point out that the provided supp file doesn’t suppress all the warnings that it should. Does it do it for you?